# Is it possible to terminate a Go channel to a sink goroutine?

Tags: go, concurrency

I have a goroutine that reads a file in chunks and passes them through a channel to another goroutine that calculates a checksum for the file. The consuming goroutine is kind of a sink for the channel.

Is it possible to have the consumer return the checksum string after all of the bytes have been received from the channel, or must I use a string stream to return the value?  For the former, I get a deadlock, but I am not using any waitgroups; Not sure how to apply them in this case.

I'd appreciate your comments and thank you for your help.

```
// main()
    var done = make(chan bool)
    defer close(done)
    checksum := FileCheckSum(ReadFileToChannel("mydata4.bin", done), done)
    fmt.Println("Final Checksum: ", checksum)
```

```
// FileCheckSum()
import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/hex"
    "log"
)

func FileCheckSum(cin <-chan []byte, done <-chan bool) string {

    chunkStream := make(chan []byte)
    checksum := func(in <-chan []byte, done <-chan bool) string {
        defer close(chunkStream)
        
        hasher := sha256.New()

        for chunk := range in {
            _, err := hasher.Write(chunk[:len(chunk)])

            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }

            select {
            case <-done:
                return ""
            }
        }

        return hex.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil))
    }(cin, done)
    return checksum
}
```

Comment: Sorry to critique your code, but I'll suggest that simply using the `io.Reader`/`io.Writer` interfaces and related helper functions will probably be more efficient and easier to implement. It seems you may be reinventing the wheel here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and let me simplify your code - and read comments inside the following code.
Try [this](https://go.dev/play/p/zbpzPcvfMnt):

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func FileCheckSum(cin <-chan []byte) string {
    h := sha256.New()

    for buf := range cin {
        _, err := h.Write(buf)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }

    return hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
}

func ReadFileToChannel(filename string) chan []byte {
    gen := make(chan []byte)
    go func() { // goroutine
        defer close(gen)          // signal end of reading file
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ { // e.g. read from file
            b := make([]byte, 16)  // make new slice every time
            _, err := rand.Read(b) // fill it
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            gen <- b // send it
        }
    }()
    return gen
}

func main() {
    ch := ReadFileToChannel("mydata4.bin")
    crc := FileCheckSum(ch)
    fmt.Println("Final Checksum: ", crc)
}
```

Output:

```
Final Checksum:  1e0ad2ec11bfe77833af670c6de296f530c2217d18aa1b8e600feddf6998fb95
```

---

### Note

Your code needs a code review, you may head over [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go) for the code review.